# Copy oldtable to newTable base on pivot query result?

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I have a pivot query from pivoted table*(a dynamic columns)*, my problem is I want to copy/clone the pivot result into new_table. Which is I don't know how to do it,

[image]
Query:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT','+QUOTENAME(c.ReportedDate)
FROM dbo.Activity c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT  b.Description, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), reportedDate, 120) as reportedDate,Status 
FROM Activity left join ActivityType b on b.activityTypeId = Activity.ActivityTypeId ) 
AS t PIVOT  (   COUNT(reportedDate)    FOR reportedDate IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ') AS p ;'
 EXECUTE (@query);
```

How to achieve my expectations to get the same result from pivotTable to new_table with the same data result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table (or a global temporary table) to store data via select into, so you will able to have access on it.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT','+QUOTENAME(c.ReportedDate)
FROM dbo.Activity c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @query = 'SELECT * into ##results FROM (SELECT  b.Description, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), reportedDate, 120) as reportedDate,Status 
FROM Activity left join ActivityType b on b.activityTypeId = Activity.ActivityTypeId ) 
AS t PIVOT  (   COUNT(reportedDate)    FOR reportedDate IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ') AS p ;'
  EXECUTE (@query);

SELECT * FROM ##results
```